# PHP DomDocument get anchor tag href and inner html?

Tags: php

The below code get's all the anchor tags and inner text on a page.  What if the inner html is an image?
For example `<a href="test.html"><img src="test.png"/></a>`  How do i get the src of image?

```
            $url = $_POST['url'];
            $html = file_get_contents($url);
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);

            //Get all links. 
            $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

            //Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
            foreach ($links as $link){
                //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
                $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
                $text = $link->nodeValue;
            }
```

How do i solve?

Comment: It's an attribute, so you should be able to find it with the getAttribute function, once you find the img node itself (by looking at the children of the anchor)

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

The [DOMXPath class](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php) is very suitable for such problems.

```
$html = '<a href="test.html"><img src="test.png"/></a><a href="example.com">Click me!</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xPath->query('//a/img/@src');

//test output
foreach($nodes as $node){
  echo $node->nodeName." : ".$node->textContent.'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
src : test.png
```

or if the href attributes are also required use

```
$nodes = $xPath->query('//a/img/@src|//a/@href');
```

and you get

```
href : test.html
src : test.png
href : example.com
```

Another variant:

```
$nodes = $xPath->query('//a/img/@src|//a[not(img)]/text()');
```

Result:

```
src : test.png
#text : Click me!
```